# Is 3-SAT polynomially equivalent to INDEPENDENT-SET

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, np

I know that 3-SAT is polynomially reducable to INDEPENDENT-SET problem.
Now is an INDEPENDENT-SET problem polynomially reducable to 3-SAT problem ? Thus are these problems polynomially equivalent?

I think it is, as every instance of INDEPENDENT-SET problem according to me can be represented in 3-SAT ( in some cases after adding a few extra edges ). However I am not clear about this understanding of mine.

Please help me our here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about theoretical computer science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the independent set problem can be reduced to 3SAT in polynomial time. The decision problem "given a graph G and number k, is there an independent set in G of size at least k?" is in NP (do you see why?). Since 3SAT is NP-complete, all problems in NP are polynomial-time reducible to it, and therefore the independent set problem is reducible to it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This also means independent-set is np complete, right?